# MarkLogic-no data reflected in View

Tags: view, marklogic

I am very new to MarkLogic and still exploring its various capabilities. I have ingested a sample csv file using MLCP and can see the each of the rows stored as a document. I then successfully created a view on this data, so that I could create reports in Tableau. However the view seems to be empty and I cant figure out why. Any inputs would be appreciated - so thanks in advance.

The curl command used to create the view is as below:

```
curl -X POST  --anyauth --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" 
-d '
{
     "view-name": "view_sales",
     "element-scope":{"namespace-uri":"", "localname":"sales"},
     "column": [
       {
         "column-name": "Country",
         "element-reference": {
            "namespace-uri": "",
            "localname": "Country",
            "scalar-type": "string"
         }
       },
       { "column-name": "Product",
         "element-reference": {
            "namespace-uri": "",
            "localname": "Product",
            "scalar-type": "string"
         }
       },
       {
         "column-name": "Fiscal_Year",
         "element-reference": {
            "namespace-uri": "",
            "localname": "Fiscal_Year",
            "scalar-type": "int"
         }
    },
       {
         "column-name": "Total_Rev",
         "element-reference": {
            "namespace-uri": "",
            "localname": "Total_Rev",
            "scalar-type": "decimal"         }
       }
     ]
   }'
http://192.168.44.12:8002/manage/v2/databases/Sales/view-schemas/Schema_Sales/views?format=json
```

Comment: read this and format your code .
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your content, and elaborate on how you tested the views? It might be a good start to open up Query Console, and start checking with that..

Comment: Thanks for responding @grtjn
My sample data looks like this in the csv file:

`Country,Product,Fiscal_Year,Total_rev
SG  Singapore,2016,BDL K1482V160 UK   Display E19 7 LED UK,2767.57
`
I used view:views("schema_sales") and Curl GET command to confirm view creation.
Also when I type in select * from view_sales in the Query Console(SQL mode),it returns "your query returns an empty sequence". I can see the view when connecting to ML via Tableau. So I assumed I missed something during the view creation or do I have to actually load data into the view?
Confused.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I had defined the element scope incorrectly. Once I rectified that, I was able to view the data!